# Como deformar um botão?

Tags: c#, winforms

Como faço para deformar um botão, usando o evento Paint do botão para ter a forma da tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd> ou até a forma de um círculo?

Comment: Olá, bem vindo(a) ao SOPT. Há inúmeras formas de fazer isso, por isso vou votar pra fechar sua pergunta como muito ampla. Uma forma possível é criar um componente customizado e implementar o método de pintura. Há inúmeros tutoriais a esse respeito, como por exemplo, esse: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pd-S6UoQHh8

Comment: @LuizVieira já me responderam porque vais fechar? oque o ramaral respondeu pode ser a resposta para outras pessoas.

Comment: @Pekita Apesar de ter respondido fui o primeiro a votar para fechar. A pergunta está ampla, no entanto pode ser editada e facilmente ser tornada mais objectiva.

Comment: @ramaral Melhor?

Comment: Eu comentei porque estava olhando a sua pergunta na fila de análise, e admito que não percebi (lá, na fila de análise) que ela já tinha uma resposta. A resposta é realmente útil, mas a pergunta continua sendo ampla porque há muitas outras formas de fazer o que você pediu. Você poderia, por exemplo, utilizar uma imagem em um botão "normal". Mas como você acabou de editar pra especificar que deseja fazer isso como componente customizado, eu vou retirar meu voto pra fechar porque a resposta **aceita** atende completamente.

Comment: Mas note como a sua edição acabou de tornar inválida [a outra resposta que você tinha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/148360/73). Esse é o problema de perguntas amplas. Elas dificultam a sua vida (como pessoa que perguntou, porque pode receber respostas que não são exatamente as que você queria) e dos demais da comunidade (porque as pessoas gastam seu tempo respondendo coisas que podem não servir ao autor da pergunta). Que lhe sirva de experiência e aprendizado pro futuro. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Tem razão. As coisas pioraram. Não pensei na outra resposta quando propôs a edição

Comment: @ramaral a minha pergunta ficou pior?

Comment: @ramaral Não acho que pioraram muito. A alteração validou mais a sua resposta e, na minha opinião, deixou mesmo a pergunta mais objetiva (e, afinal, já estava aceita). Piorou um pouco porque a outra resposta (que ia na linha de usar o componente de botão existente) já não serve. Mas a pergunta ficou mesmo mais objetiva.

Comment: @Pekita Ficou melhor porque "encaixa" a minha resposta mas ficou pior porque invalida a resposta do Bruno.

Comment: @ramaral então como posso encaixar na resposta dos dois?

Comment: Não vejo como. No entanto há sempre a possibilidade de você reverter a edição.

Comment: @ramaral mas se eu reverter a edição as pessoas iram votar para fechar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uma forma simples é responder ao evento [Paint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) do botão, desenhar aí a forma pretendida e atribuí-la à propriedade [Region](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region(v=vs.110).aspx) do botão.

Exemplo para um botão circular([fonte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region(v=vs.110).aspx))

```
//Este método transforma a forma do botão standard em circular,
// criando um forma em circulo e atribuindo-a à propriedade region do botão
private void roundButton_Paint(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{

    System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath buttonPath = 
        new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();

    //Cria um rectangulo com o mesmo tamanho que o botão
    System.Drawing.Rectangle newRectangle = roundButton.ClientRectangle;

    // Diminui o tamanho do ractangulo.
    newRectangle.Inflate(-10, -10);

    // Desenha a borda do botão.
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(System.Drawing.Pens.Black, newRectangle);

    // Aumenta o tamanho do rectangulo para incluir a borda.
    newRectangle.Inflate( 1,  1);

    // Cria um circulo dentr0 do rectangulo.
    buttonPath.AddEllipse(newRectangle);

    //Atribui o circuloa propriedade region
    roundButton.Region = new System.Drawing.Region(buttonPath);

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Pekita, o melhor que pode ser feito com o Button padrão do WinForms (ao menos ao meu entender) é definir seu estilo para Flat (FlatStyle = Flat), remover suas bordas (FlatAppearence.BorderSize = 0) e definir uma imagem como BackgroundImage.

Do contrário podes criar um componente personalizado com as dimensões e especificações que quiseres, porém a implementação e o layout deste devem ser feitas manualmente, obviamente podendo herdar do objeto Button padrão.

Um exemplo de como poderia ser feito ao meu entender seria a junção de várias imagens quadrangulares que formariam juntas a forma do botão "Enter" e quando qualquer uma destas imagens for pressionada o clique do botão é disparado.

Talvez esta não seja a solução mais adequada, mas foi o que consegui pensar para te ajudar. Sugiro que aguarde para identificar outras possíveis sugestões ou respostas.

Comment: Veja, a resposta estava ampla. Dai você deu a sua resposta, que estava boa. Mas com a edição do AP a sua resposta se tornou menos válida. :/  Mesmo assim, te dei meu +1 porque a resposta merecia antes. :)

Comment: Peço desculpa por a minha sugestão, para o AP editar a pergunta, ter invalidado a sua resposta.

Comment: De forma alguma ramaral, sem problemas. Estamos aqui para contribuir com a comunidade e a resposta que foi aceita indica uma melhor solução para o problema proposto pela pergunta, ainda que após a edição. Tenho certeza que o Pekita aproveitou melhor a resposta dada por você neste contexto.